# PrimeNG popup menu with header

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to create popup navigation menu component with links to pages and a header (2 lines of text - user Name and server status with some styling). I already have an app with primeNG so I'd like to stick with that over installing some more dependencies, wanted to use Menu component, but there is an issue with styling the header part of the menu. Is there an easy way to achieve that without setting disabled on 1st item and styling it through .menu-container ul li:nth-child(1) ? I dont really also like the fact that I need to build the header as 'fake' menu item through MenuModel.
Alternatively what other component would fit these requirements

Answer (score 0):

Settled with panel overlay as it allows defining own HTML. Needed to do more styling to define it nicely but at least I didn't have to hack the header.